# Как свернуть узлы дерева решения в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Одной из неприятных особенностей Visual Studio является то, что по умолчанию она в дереве обозревателя решений раскрывает все узлы по проекты включительно. Когда в решении несколько десятков проектов, а иногда и сотен проектов, это очень неудобно. Студия сохраняет состояние узлов в файле .suo, но после взятия из-под контроля версий новой версии решения со структурными изменениями, этот файл либо сам слетает, либо вешает Студию, и его приходится удалять, и всё повторяется снова.

Может, у Студии есть какие-нибудь настройки, позволяющие задавать состояние узлов в обозревателе решений по умолчанию?

Может, есть какой-нибудь плагин, позволяющий это настраивать?

Может, тут кто-нибудь знает, как написать такой плагин?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этих целей использую Visual Studio Power Tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vstudio/bb980963), в котором есть ещё и другие полезные вещи.

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Какой из тулкитов ставить, где искать настройки?

Comment: Ставить Power Tools по ссылке выше. После этого появится новый пункт контектного меню при нажатии ни солюшен. Подробнее о возможностях лучше читать на MSDN

Comment: хм, там ещё и для 2010 Студии. Мы пока на 2008 сидим :(

Comment: Для VS2008 есть аналогичный плагин http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего всякие файлы типа .suo, .ncb, .sdf, .user, ipch, создаваемые студией, исключить из контроля версий. Эти файлы не предназначены для сохранения в репозиторий, так как одни (.ncb, .sdf, .ipch) содержат кэши (которые большие и бинарные, и смысла их грузить нет, кроме того они могут быть machine-specific), а другие (.suo, .user) содержат информацию, нужную только локальному пользователю. Понятно, что это не относится к файлам .sln, .vcproj, vcxproj, .filters и т.д. - их сохранять желательно :)

Расширения файлов я написал из нескольких версий студии в одну кучу, не обязательно, что все эти файлы есть у вас.

Кстати, в 2010 студии (а может, уже и в 2008, не помню) локальные настройки (например, настройки отладки) уже явно вынесли в файл .user, чтобы было понятно, что его не надо сохранять.

Comment: Мы так и делаем.

Comment: Ясно, значит, я неправильно понял. Я подумал, что проблема в том, что .suo у вас в репозитории. Вероятно, просто студия не умеет хорошо обрабатывать обновление структуры проекта. Кстати, в 2010 у меня таких зависов не было ни разу, так что возможно, что Microsoft это исправила.